# Is my interpretation of "and" correct in these statements?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

Let A mean "Equation A has a solution" and B mean "Equation B has no solution." I am a little confused, so I wrote down some possibilities and I wish to see if my interpretation of the following is correct:

1. Equations A and B both have no solutions. In symbols: ~A /\  ~B.
2. Neither equation A nor B has a solution. In symbols: ~(A \/ B).
3. Both equations A and B have no solutions. In symbols: ~(A \/ B).

If I'm correct, I want to know intuitively the difference between (1) and (3). Thanks.

Comment: The three statements are all logically equivalent, there is no difference truth-functionally. But if B is supposed to mean "Equation B has *no* solution", then you need to invert the negations on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For statements 1 and 3 you are looking at examples of De Morgan's Laws.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

The complement of the union of two sets is the same as the intersection of their complements; and
The complement of the intersection of two sets is the same as the union of their complements.
or

```
not (A or B) = not A and not B; and
not (A and B) = not A or not B
```

And LemontTree has a good point as well.